# Can I use a messages.yml file instead of messages.properties for message codes

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, properties, internationalization, yaml

Can I use `messages.yml` in place of `messages.properties` to define internationalization of messages.

I tried it, it doesn't work, can anyone help what else needs to be done?

My resolver looks like this

```java
@Bean
    public ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource() {
        ResourceBundleMessageSource rs = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
        rs.setBasename("i18n/messages");
        rs.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        rs.setUseCodeAsDefaultMessage(true);
        return rs;
    }
```

I have put `messages.yml` under `resources/i18n/`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Currently its not supported by default as you can see from this feature request which has been closed due to be realtively unrelevant: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/18990

Comment: We have reopened this issue, I just pushed a fix for it and combined with a custom `PropertyPersister` this is now possible, more details on [this comment](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/18990#issuecomment-1663927493).

Would be nice to update the answer accordingly.